# What means the second parameter in a Python nested list?

Tags: python, list, nested

I built a nested list like this

```
List1 = ["Smith", "John", "Boston"]
List2 = ["Brown", "Jim", "New York"]
customers = [[List1], [List2]]
print(customers)
```

> [[['Smith', 'John', 'Boston']], [['Brown', 'Jim', 'New York']]]

To access the elements of the list(s) I have to add a second parameter, which I don't understand.

```
i=0 
while i<=len(customers)-1:
    print(customers[i][0][0], customers[i][0][1], customers[i][0][2])
    i+=1
```

> Smith John Boston Brown Jim New York

Why the [0] in the middle? Why not simply [i][1]? Can you help me?

Comment: Are you aware that ``[[List1], [List2]]`` is a list of lists *of lists*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are creating list of list

```
customers = [[List1], [[List2]]
```

if you had written  `customers = [List1, List2]` then there is no need of middle index.

```
List1 = ["Smith", "John", "Boston"]
List2 = ["Brown", "Jim", "New York"]
customers = [List1, List2]
print(customers)

[['Smith', 'John', 'Boston'], ['Brown', 'Jim', 'New York']]

i=0
while i<=len(customers)-1:
    print(customers[i][0], customers[i][1], customers[i][2])
    i+=1

Smith John Boston
Brown Jim New York
```

Comment: The first code snippet doesn't give the output you indicate - please run your code for real before posting it. The second snippet gives `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Fundaments

- `a = ["Smith", "John", "Boston"]` is a list. You can access its first
  item via `a[0]`
- `b = [a]` is same as `b = [["Smith", "John", "Boston"]]` which is a list of list.

  - `b[0]`:  will be first item which is the list `["Smith", "John", "Boston"]`
  - `b[0][0]`: will be first item of the first item which will be `Smith`
  - `b[0][0][0]`: will be first item of the first item of the first item which will be `S`
- `b = [[a]]` is same as `b = [[["Smith", "John", "Boston"]]]` which is a list of a list of list (3 nested lists).

  - `b[i][j][k]`: will return `k`th item of the `j`th item at the `i`th position in `b` so `b[0][0][0]` will return the first item of first item of first item of b which is `Smith`